# Best way to limit access model to owner or superuser

Tags: django

I need to limit access to model object only to user created it or superuser.

For example:

```
post = get_object_or_404(Post, slug=kwargs['slug'])
if post.created_by == request.user or request.user.is_superuser:
    return render(request, "post.html", {"post": post})
```

Is there better practice\shortcut for this ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there are some shortcuts. If you use class based views then you can use [class decorator](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/class-based-views/intro/#decorating-the-class).
Also you can use decorators in `urls.py` file. [Here's how](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/class-based-views/intro/#decorating-in-urlconf).

Answer (score 0):

Creating a decorator is always cleaner

```
from functools import wraps

from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404, redirect
from django.utils.decorators import available_attrs


def user_can_view():
    def decorator(view_func):
        @wraps(view_func, assigned=available_attrs(view_func))
        def _wrapped_view(request, *args, **kwargs):

            post = get_object_or_404(Post, slug=kwargs['slug'])
            if post.created_by == request.user or request.user.is_superuser:
                return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

            # Redirct to another view or raise 404 instead
            return redirect('posts')
        return _wrapped_view
    return decorator


@user_can_view()
def my_view(request):
    return render(request, "post.html", {"post": post})
```